# Is It Possible to Implement Rule-Based Access Control on Amazon Web Services?

Tags: aws, rbac

I've gone through a few security tutorials on AWS and noted that each tutorial focused on role-based access control only.  Has anyone used **rule**-based access control on AWS?  If so, could you point me to links or documentation?

Comment: what is "rule"-based access control?

Answer (score 1):

You mean attribute-based? Yes it is possible. AWS has several ways to do that e.g. AWS IAM which can be used across AWS services. In some cases you can also use resource-based policies (AWS API gateway). Lastly, there are companies e.g. Axiomatics and Savyint who also address this need.